# Azure Table Storage - UpsertAsync Error in PROD

Tags: azure, azure-tableclient

We have deployed the application on the Azure. We got an error while calling the
Azure tableclient's "UpsertEntityAsync" function.
await tableClient.UpsertEntityAsync (entity);

Error Message:  Error Message Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy., StackTrace:    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Azure.Data.Tables.TableRestClient.d__33.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient.d__49`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)

Please help on this issue.

Comment: The error message you're encountering indicates that the "UpsertEntityAsync" function from Azure Table Storage is failing due to a retry policy exceeding the maximum number of retries. We can catch specific exceptions that might occur during the "UpsertEntityAsync" operation and handle them accordingly. For example, We can catch `RequestFailedException` and log the error details to understand the specific cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, the `UpsertEntityAsync` function from Azure Table Storage is failing because a retry policy exceeded the maximum number of retries. Certain exceptions can be detected and managed during the `UpsertEntityAsync` process. To determine the reason for the problem, we can use the `RequestFailedException` exception to track the error details.

- Create Azure storage and Table.

[image]

```cs
        var serviceClient = new TableServiceClient(connectionString);

        // Create a TableClient for your specific table
        var tableClient = serviceClient.GetTableClient(tableName);

        // Create an entity to upsert
        var entity = new TableEntity("PartitionKey", "RowKey")
        {
            { "PropertyName", "PropertyValue" }
        };

        try
        {
            // Attempt to upsert the entity
            await tableClient.UpsertEntityAsync(entity);
            Console.WriteLine("Entity upserted successfully.");
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
        {
            // Log or handle the exception
            Console.WriteLine($"Error code: {ex.Status}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Error message: {ex.Message}");
            // Handle the error appropriately.
        }
    }
}
```

- The table parameters that I modified.

```
var entity = new TableEntity("part1", "row1")
{
    { "name", "Sam" }
};
```

**Output:**

[image]